# Query work in PhpMyAdmin but does not work in php codes

Tags: php, mysql, api, mysqli

i wrote a code that insert in two table in one time that tables connect with each other with foreign key .
i search in this site but did not find an answer .
this query worked in phpmyadmin but have false answer in php code and does not work in php ....why??? :( 
this is my Query and code in php.... please help me

```
INSERT INTO `interviewdeliverytable` ( `FirstName` , `LastName` , `PhoneNumber` , `PostCode` , `IdNumebr` , `BirthDate` , `Address` , `Accepted` , `IsBike` , `Date` )
VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$PhoneNumber', '$PostCode', '$IdNumber', '$BirthDate', '$Address', '$Accepted', '$IsBike', '$Date');
SELECT @Var := Last_INSERT_ID() ;
INSERT INTO `interviewbiketable` (`PhoneNumber` , `DriverLicenseId` , `BikeModel` , `PelakNumebr` ,`Accepted`,`IsBike`, DeliveryId )
VALUES ('$PhoneNumber', '$DeliverLicenseId', '$BikeModel', '$PelakNumber','$Accepted','$IsBike', @Var)
```

php codes

```
function registerDelivery(){
$connection=createConnection();
if(!$connection){
    echo "Error";
}else{
//
//get objects
//
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$FirstName=$obj->FirstName;
$LastName=$obj->LastName;
$PostCode=$obj->PostCode;
$IdNumber=$obj->IdNumebr;
$BirthDate=$obj->BirthDate;
$Address=$obj->Address;
$Accepted=$obj->Accepted;
$IsBike=$obj->IsBike;
$Date=$obj->Date;
$DeliverLicenseId=$obj->DriverLicenseId;
$BikeModel=$obj->BikeModel;
$PelakNumber=$obj->PelakNumebr;
$PhoneNumber=$obj->PhoneNumber;
//
//insert Query
//
$result=mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `interviewdeliverytable` ( `FirstName` , `LastName` , `PhoneNumber` , `PostCode` , `IdNumebr` , `BirthDate` , `Address` , `Accepted` , `IsBike` , `Date` )
VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$PhoneNumber', '$PostCode', '$IdNumber', '$BirthDate', '$Address', '$Accepted', '$IsBike', '$Date');
SELECT @Var := Last_INSERT_ID() ;
INSERT INTO `interviewbiketable` (`PhoneNumber` , `DriverLicenseId` , `BikeModel` , `PelakNumebr` ,`Accepted`,`IsBike`, DeliveryId )
VALUES ('$PhoneNumber', '$DeliverLicenseId', '$BikeModel', '$PelakNumber','$Accepted','$IsBike', @Var)");
echo json_encode(array('Result'=>$result));
mysqli_close($connection);
```

}
}

Comment: Why the SELECT?

Comment: it should select last insert id and insert into another table that has foreign key 'Delivery id'. have you a way to do that

Comment: Is the quoted string all one line in your PHP code? In the posted code it isn't, and that makes it _not_ a string.

Comment: Can we have more info about the actual error? "false answer" means what? You don't get the result you're expecting? You don't get a result at all? It's throwing an error?

Comment: You don't need a separate query to 'get' the last insert id.

Comment: {"Result":false} this is my result that return query result in '$result' variable and convert to json array ....i have connection and i dont have any error

Comment: it just does not insert my data to table in php code . but this query command worked in phpmyadmin...

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all
i Edited  my Queries...

```
function registerDelivery(){
$connection=createConnection();
if(!$connection){
    echo "Error";
}else{
//
//get objects
//
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$FirstName=$obj->FirstName;
$LastName=$obj->LastName;
$PostCode=$obj->PostCode;
$IdNumber=$obj->IdNumebr;
$BirthDate=$obj->BirthDate;
$Address=$obj->Address;
$Accepted=$obj->Accepted;
$IsBike=$obj->IsBike;
$Date=$obj->Date;
$DeliverLicenseId=$obj->DriverLicenseId;
$BikeModel=$obj->BikeModel;
$PelakNumber=$obj->PelakNumebr;
$PhoneNumber=$obj->PhoneNumber;
//
//insert Query
//
$result=mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `interviewdeliverytable` ( `FirstName` , `LastName` , `PhoneNumber` , `PostCode` , `IdNumebr` , `BirthDate` , `Address` , `Accepted` , `IsBike` , `Date` )
VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$PhoneNumber', '$PostCode', '$IdNumber', '$BirthDate', '$Address', '$Accepted', '$IsBike', '$Date');");
 if($result){
     printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $connection->insert_id);
     $id=$connection->insert_id;
      if($id!=null){
          $resFinall=mysqli_query($connection,
          "INSERT INTO `interviewbiketable` (`PhoneNumber` , `DriverLicenseId` , `BikeModel` , `PelakNumebr` ,`Accepted`,`IsBike`, DeliveryId ) VALUES ('$PhoneNumber', '$DeliverLicenseId', '$BikeModel', '$PelakNumber','$Accepted','$IsBike', '$id');");
           echo json_encode(array('Result'=>$resFinall));
      }}
```

it worked and insert all data in two tables ...thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

This is not a query but a *set of multiple queries*. Therefore you have to run them separately one by one:

```
mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO ...");
$id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO ...");
```

Note that you should be using  prepared statements for your queries.

Comment: thanks please write code better i do not about php very much..please explain more

Comment: explain more please :)

Comment: @CodeForLife This answer is abundantly clear if you take time to read it carefully and try this advice. One query at a time.